# Nested association has_many;through doesn't update collection_check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested, simple-form

Using check boxes to update the nested form I can't update the tables. I received following message:

> Unpermitted parameter: :category
>   ActionController::Parameters
>   {"name"=>"Flux Capacitor", "price"=>"19.55"} permitted: true

I have tried different ways to fix this through the permitted params, including a `:category` parameter, like so:

```rb
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:id, :name, :price, :category, categories_attributes: [:id, :name, :category], categorizations_attributes: [:id, :product_id, :category_ids, :category])
end
```

My models

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories, reject_if: proc {|attributes| attributes['name'].blank?}
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations
end
```

```rb
class Categorization < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product, inverse_of: :categorizations
  belongs_to :category, inverse_of: :categorizations
end
```

```rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :products, through: :categorizations, inverse_of: :category
end
```

```rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def new
   @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    if @product.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Product succesfully created'
      redirect_to products_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = 'Product was not created'
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @product.update(product_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Product succesfully updated"
      redirect_to products_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = 'Product was not updated'
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

app/view/products/edit.html.erb

```html
<%= simple_form_for(@product) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :price %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for @product.categories do |cats| %>
    <%= cats.collection_check_boxes  :ids, Category.all, :id, :name, collection_wrapper_tag: :ul, item_wrapper_tag: :li %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

This seems like something that is common enough that rails and/or simple_form, should provide in a more built-in way to do this. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly you should be able to do this without the use of accepts_nested_attributes_for or simple_fields_for.  Try something like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@product) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :price %>
  <%= f.association :categories, as: :check_boxes %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

your strong params should look something like this:

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:id, :name, :price, { category_ids: [] }])
end
```

Comment: It works!. Excellent, many thanks @Ben_Trewem. But now I'm more confuse. 1) How come don't need the 'accepts_nested_attributes_for' helper, been clearly a nested form of two models? . Presumably due to the association field type of simple_form. 2) Why instead of using the category parameters, it is necessary to use 'category_ids' to pass the parameters to the product's update method . 3) Where are the links to the information that allows simple mortals, to learn and understand the mechanics and concepts around these issues?. Thanks again.

Comment: What you've got is a habtm association between products and categories using categorizations as the join table.  simple_form supports these types of associations and just passes the category ids to the association.You have to add the category_ids to the strong parameters permit to allow those parameters to be mass assigned in your create / update actions.